# How to Create Virtual Directory on Remote Machine

Tags: asp.net

I am able to create Virtual Directory on local machine, but I want to create it on a remote machine.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager you could connect a remote server and manage it locally.

[image]

Comment: @BreakHead, in IIS Manager, click on `Connect to a server...` and type the remote server name. Once the remote server is connected you can expand and administer it.

Comment: it throws access denied error, and I dnt kno the Username and password?

Comment: @BreakHead, if you don't have administrative privileges to the remote machine you cannot manage IIS and create virtual directories. You need to be administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Allow remote IIS manager to create virtual directories

https://forums.iis.net/p/1163088/1926748.aspx

Here are some similar cases for you to check about :

How to Create IIS Virtual Directories in Visual Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs.aspx

How to create a virtual directory on an existing Web site to a folder that resides on a remote computer

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308150